# api rest яндекс диск создать папку

Tags: php, curl, rest

пытаюсь создать паку на диске в результате получаю такую ошибку помогите исправить `{"message":"Метод не поддерживается.","description":"Method Not Allowed","error":"MethodNotAllowedError"}`
 вот мой createPath.php

```html
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/html',
    'charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization: xxx',
);
$path = curl_init();
curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources?path=".$_POST['path']);
curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET', CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'path');
$resultpath = curl_exec($path);
curl_close($path);
$arrpath = json_decode($resultpath, true);
```

код index.php

```html
<form method='POST' action='createPath.php'>
    <input type='text' name='path' value=''>
    <button type='submit'></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Моя ошибка заключалась в неправильном написании кода
нужно так чтобы всё работало

```html
<form method='POST' action='createPath.php'>
    <input type='text' name='path' value=''>
    <button type='submit'></button>
</form>
```

и код createPath.php

```html
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/html',
    'charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization: ваш токен',
);

$path = curl_init();
curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources?path=".$_POST["path"]."");
curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
//curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'path');
curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, false);
    curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
$resultpath = curl_exec($path);
curl_close($path);
$arrpath = json_decode($resultpath, true);
```

должно быть так `curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");` а не так `curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET', CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`
 и не важно что там будет PUT или GET  работать не будет , а так да что бы папка создалась нужен метод PUT

Answer (score 1):

Запрос создания папки следует отправлять с помощью метода PUT.

Comment: сделал так не сработало curl_setopt($path, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT', CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

Comment: curl -H "Authorization: OAuth <token>" "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources?path=/folder1" -X PUT

Comment: у меня всё тоже выдает